# SlidesJS Display:none not working properly

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I've recently started to code a site for a friend and he asked me if I could add a slideshow to the site to display images. So because I don't know Javascript I found an open-source and free slideshow I could use called SlidesJS. I have managed to customise everything but now when the images are displayed on the slideshow instead of sliding across and being shown on the slideshow, they slide across the whole screen covering other content so it gets quite annoying. I have tried display:none to try hide the images as they slide into place but it doesn't seem to work!
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="ss">

    <div id="slides">
        <div class="slides_container">
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/jliba/4665625073/" title="145.365 - Happy Bokeh Thursday! | Flickr - Photo Sharing!" target="_blank"><img src="img/slide-1.jpg" width="692" height="395" alt="Slide 1"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/stephangeyer/3020487807/" title="Taxi | Flickr - Photo Sharing!" target="_blank"><img src="img/slide-2.jpg" width="690" height="395" alt="Slide 2"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/childofwar/2984345060/" title="Happy Bokeh raining Day | Flickr - Photo Sharing!" target="_blank"><img src="img/slide-3.jpg" width="690" height="395" alt="Slide 3"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/b-tal/117037943/" title="We Eat Light | Flickr - Photo Sharing!" target="_blank"><img src="img/slide-4.jpg" width="690" height="395" alt="Slide 4"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/bu7amd/3447416780/" title="&ldquo;I must go down to the sea again, to the lonely sea and the sky; and all I ask is a tall ship and a star to steer her by.&rdquo; | Flickr - Photo Sharing!" target="_blank"><img src="img/slide-5.jpg" width="690" height="395" alt="Slide 5"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/streetpreacher/2078765853/" title="twelve.inch | Flickr - Photo Sharing!" target="_blank"><img src="img/slide-6.jpg" width="690" height="395" alt="Slide 6"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/aftab/3152515428/" title="Save my love for loneliness | Flickr - Photo Sharing!" target="_blank"><img src="img/slide-7.jpg" width="690" height="395" alt="Slide 7"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="img/arrow-prev.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Prev"></a>
        <a href="#" class="next"><img src="img/arrow-next.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Next"></a>
    </div>
    <img src="img/example-frame.png" alt="Example Frame" name="frame" width="739" height="341" id="frame">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ss {
width:900px;
height:500px;
position:relative;
margin-left:30px;
}


#frame {
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
width:900px;
height:500px;
top:-3px;
left:-80px;

}

/*
Slideshow
*/

#slides {
position:absolute;
top:24px;
left:24px;
z-index:100;
}

/* 
Slides container
Important:
Set the width of your slides container
Set to display none, prevents content flash
*/ 

.slides_container {
width:900px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
display:none;
}

/*
Each slide
Important:
Set the width of your slides
If height not specified height will be set by the slide content
Set to display block
*/

.slides_container div.slide {
width:692px;
height:395px;
display:none;
}


/*
Next/prev buttons
*/

#slides .next,#slides .prev {
position:absolute;
top:165px;
left:-44px;
width:24px;
height:43px;
display:block;
z-index:101;
}

#slides .next {
left:710px;
}

/*
Pagination
*/

.pagination {
margin:26px auto 0;
width:100px;
margin-left:260px;
}

.pagination li {
float:left;
margin:0 1px;
list-style:none;
}

.pagination li a {
display:block;
width:12px;
height:0;
padding-top:12px;
background-image:url(../img/pagination.png);
background-position:0 0;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
}

.pagination li.current a {
background-position:0 -12px;
}




ThankYou in Advance.
```

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle with your JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a the entire thing in a div with a given width and height, and add the css attribute `overflow:hidden;`